# Magento multi-store is not working with different cart or session

Tags: magento-1.8, php, cart, session

I am using a multistore setup and have an issue regarding using the same session after login.

- Site 1 : http://testsite.com/store1
- Site 2 : http://testsite.com/store2

If login with the same user and password and add a product to the cart, that product is showing up in both stores carts.

If I add something to the cart, it should only show in the store site in which I added the product, but not in the other store. What do I need to do?
Subdomain ie. `store1.testsite.com` and in that other store was created having url `store2.testsite.com`

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing cart sharing because your stores are under the same domain.  You need to set `system->config->web->session validation settings->use sid on frontend` to `no` if you have a store switcher and then have your store running under different domains/subdomains.  The `frontend` cookie contains the session id for the current session and as this and the session data are not accessible in domains other than that which they were created the session id will be unique to each store and so you will not have cart sharing anymore.  Bear in mind however that a cookie set for domain `testsite.com` will be accessible in all subdomains i.e. `store1.testsite.com` and `store2.testsite.com`.